# Handle soap response at servlet

Tags: web-services, servlets, soap

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:getPrice xmlns:ns1="urn:xmethods-BNPriceCheck">
<isbn>0672383839</isbn>
</ns1:getPrice>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

How do I handle this data on the servlet side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using a web service framework for handling SOAP. Like JAX-WS implementations ([CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/), [Metro](http://jax-ws.java.net/)).

Apart from that, I guess you can use anything that's lower level, like [SAAJ](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbhg.html) or even DOM/SAX, but it's not advisable.